# puppetdb 6.3.3 can't connect to postgresql-11

Tags: postgresql, puppetdb

semanage confirms my host is running in permissive mode.

I can login to postgresql as user puppetdb when I don't use a password like this:

`[msk@puppet ~]$ su - postgres
 Password: 
 Last login: Fri Jun 21 14:19:01 EDT 2019 on pts/1
 bash-4.2$ psql -d puppetdb -U puppetdb
 psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "puppetdb"`

**netstat -tlpn |grep postmaster** shows 
 `tcp  0  0  127.0.0.1:5432 0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  22948/postmaster`

The error I see in /var/log/puppetlabs/puppetdb/puppetdb.log by the hundred is:

```
Pool - Connection is not available, request timed out after 3012ms.
2019-06-21T13:36:50.267-04:00 ERROR [p.p.c.services] Will retry database connection after temporary failure: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: PDBMigrationsPool - Connection is not available, request timed out after 3000ms.
```

/var/lib/pgsql/11/data/pg_hba.conf contains:

```
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    puppetdb        puppetdb        127.0.0.1/32            peer
```

postgresql-Fri.log is full of

`FATAL:  remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections`

Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 0):

PuppetDB can't connect to the database. Firstly check `database.ini` file, possibly in: `/etc/puppetlabs/puppetdb/conf.d/database.ini`. It should contain something like this:

```
classname = org.postgresql.Driver
subprotocol = postgresql
subname = //localhost:5432/puppetdb
username = puppetdb
conn-max-age = 60
conn-keep-alive = 45
conn-lifetime = 0
```

Make sure set appropriate number of connections in your PostgreSQL instance, i.e. `postgresql.conf`:

```
max_connections = 64
```

Restart PostgreSQL.

Now verify as `puppetdb` user that the connection actually works:

```
su - puppetdb -s /bin/sh -c "psql -h localhost puppetdb"
```

If you're using SSL, make sure to check the [PostgreSQL SSL guide](https://puppet.com/docs/puppetdb/latest/postgres_ssl.html).

When debugging DB issues the status endpoint could be useful:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/status/v1/services | jq .
```

Answer (score 0):

/var/lib/pgsql/11/data/pg_hba.conf wanted this line added to the top of it.

**host      puppetdb    puppetdb    ::1/24          trust**

I had forgotten about posting this question. Thanks for helping :)